# Can we expose AWS machine port to Lambda function without making public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to expose a port of AWS machine to Lambda function which is integrated to AWS Gateway API. For security reasons, i don't want to make that port public. Can we achieve this?

Comment: Are there any other ports on that machine that have to be public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to place your Lambdas inside a VPC. Lambdas can run publicly or they can run from within a VPC. If they run inside a VPC their access to other resources in the same VPC is governed by VPC security groups.

You can specify VPC by modifying Lambda in AWS Console, or take a look at the official tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html#vpc-configuring